# Consume SQS messages concurrently in .net core application

Tags: .net-core, amazon-sqs

I am writing an application where I want to consume SQS messages. I've created a BackgroundService, and registered it in the startup. Works like a charm. Problem is that it processes messages **one by one**, while the hardware is capable of processing dozens of messages in parallel on a single machine. (Easy solution would be to use AWS Lambdas, but let's say I don't want to).

Is it somehow possible to have dynamic amount of background **workers**, which will be created when there is more messages in the queue, and destroyed when there is less messages?

I consider having single **main background process** that will run every 1s that will check number of messages in a queue. Then depending on amount of messages waiting in a queue it will create up to 10-20 **workers**. Each **worker** at its **startup** (different than server startup) will poll SQS, handle it's message(s) and then poll again. When poll returns zero messages, it means that this **worker** should terminate itself.

My only idea is to:

- implement **main background process** as a BackgroundService (IHostedService)
- implement **workers** as a `Task.Run(() => ... )`

but it's kind of a smelly approach. Is there anything better to solve such problem?

Comment: If you pull messages from SQS, then you can pull at max 10 messages in a single request.

Comment: @ShivanshuGupta I know. But what it have to do with my question?